# NiFi avro schema using regex to validate a string

Tags: validation, avro, apache-nifi

I have an avro schema in NiFi which validates the columns of a CSV file, all is working well, however I'd like to ideally have an extra level of validation on certain string column to test that they adhere to specific patterns. For example ABC1234-X, or whatever. Here's the wrinkle though, the avro schema is generated for specific expected files, and so the NiFi processors need to be generic.

Is there a way to have the avro schema do this?

Comment: Is the column name the same for each file you want to validate it on? Or is there a regex associated with a column name that you want to be applied for validation purposes?

Comment: So for each csv file picked up, it will have a corresponding avro schema in the schema registry. So avro knows what columns its expecting. What I need to do is for certain string columns apply a validation rule based upon a regex